# Probability distribution of random variable is shown in the table

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Probability distribution of random variable is shown in the table:
\begin{array} {|r|r|r|}
\hline
Y/X&1&5\\
\hline
1&5/9&1/9\\
\hline
2&1/9&2/9\\
\hline
\end{array}
$(A)$ if $W=X-Y$, then $P(W<0)=1/9$ ;

$(B)$ $E(X)<E(Y)$ ;

$(C)$ $E(X|Y=1)=5/3$ ;

I've already shown that $(B)$ is false, because $E(X)=1*\frac69+5*\frac39=\frac73$ and $E(Y)=1*\frac69+2*\frac39=\frac43$, so $EX>EY$,

and $(C)$: $E(X|Y=1)=1*\frac56+5*\frac16=\frac{10}{6}=\frac53$ is true.

As to $(A)$ we have: $P(W<0)=P(X-Y<0)=P(X<Y)=$... and I've got no idea how to continue this.

Comment: I’m not sure that I accurately understand your table. Is the sample space $\Bbb{U}=\{1,5\}\times\{1,2\}$? And is $\operatorname{P}(X=5\cap Y=2)=\operatorname{P}(5,2)=\frac29$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only time when X is less than Y is when X = 1 and Y = 2 and the Probability of that is $\frac{1}{9}$ Hence True